# Converting alphabet letter to alphabet position in PHP

Tags: php

```
$my_alphabet = "T";
```

The above character "T" should print the exact position/number of the alphabet. i.e 20

So, if

```
$my_alphabet = "A" ;
```

- I should be able to get the position of the alphabet. i.e. 1

How can I achieve that.

I see converting number to alphabet .. but the reverse is not there anywhere.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

By using the ascii value:

```
ord(strtoupper($letterOfAlphabet)) - ord('A') + 1
```

in ASCII the letters are sorted by alphabetic order, so...

Comment: Even though the letters at location +1 each in ascii a problem arises if uppercase AND lowercase characters can be found as b is not ord(A)+1   but ord(a) +1.  In that case either all letters need to be converted to uppercase or lowercsae (strtoupper, strtolower) OR it must be checked with ctype_upper if th letter is uppercase (then the solution from bwoebi) or if its lowercase then ord('a') instead of ord('A') has to be used.

Comment: @ThomasE. or just use a `strtoupper()` < updated answer.

Comment: bwoebi  -thanks .. this is what i want. excellent. saved my time. ;)

Answer (score 4):

In case the alphabet letter is not upper case, you can add this line of code to make sure you get the right position of the letter

```
$my_alphabet = strtoupper($my_alphabet);
```

so if you get either `'T'` or `'t'`, it will always return the right position.

Otherwise [@bwoebi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2153758/bwoebi)'s answers will perfectly do the job

Comment: i cooked bwoebi code with which i want to prepare my recipe.  thanks for ur code too

Answer (score 4):

you should be careful about (uppercase, lowercase):

```
<?php
$upperArr = range('A', 'Z') ;
$LowerArr = range('a', 'z') ;
$myLetter = 't';

if(ctype_upper($myLetter)){
    echo (array_search($myLetter, $upperArr) + 1); 
}else{
    echo (array_search($myLetter, $LowerArr) + 1); 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use upper case and lower case use this function to get the right position

```
function offset(string $char): int {
  $abcUpper = range('A', 'Z');
  $abcLower = range('a', 'z');
  if (ctype_upper($char)) return array_search($char, $abcUpper) + 1;
  else return array_search($char, $abcLower) + 1;
}
```

test

```
echo offset("a"); // 1
```

if you use an array and you want to get the position to use in an array

```
function offset(string $char): int {
  $abcUpper = range('A', 'Z');
  $abcLower = range('a', 'z');
  if (ctype_upper($char)) return array_search($char, $abcUpper);
  else return array_search($char, $abcLower);
}
```

test

```
echo offset("a"); // 0
```